# Why is addToSet in mongodb not working in an array field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

The documents in the collection have an array field of sub-documents, each with a counter that should be increased up to three, but if the array doesn't have a sub-document with a given key it should create it with the default values.

The documentation for [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) says:

> **Behavior**
>
> $addToSet only ensures that there are no duplicate items added to the set and does not affect existing duplicate elements. $addToSet does not guarantee a particular ordering of elements in the modified set.
>
> **Missing Field**
>
> If you use $addToSet on a field is absent in the document to update, $addToSet creates the array field with the specified value as its element.

The problem is that the array field is not created in the document if it doesn't exist, as stated in the documentation.

This is what I'm currently using to accomplish the operation:

```
// increase counter in element of array if element exist and counter is less than 3
collection.updateOne({
        key_1,
        "array.key_2": key_2,
        "array.counter": {$lt: 3}
    }, {
        $inc: {"array.$.counter": 1}
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log("!!!!1:", res.modifiedCount, res.upsertedId, res.upsertedCount, res.matchedCount);

        if (res.matchedCount) return res.matchedCount;

        // create element in array with the default values,
        // also create the array field if it doesn't exist
        collection.updateOne({
                key_1
            }, {
                $addToSet: {
                    array: {key_2, counter: 1}
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log("!!!!2:", res.modifiedCount, res.upsertedId, res.upsertedCount, res.matchedCount);
                return res.matchedCount;
            })
            .catch(e => console.log(e))
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Using `upsert` in the second query, it creates the array field if it doesn't exist but then when `array.counter` reaches 3 in subsequent calls to increase its value, the operation creates a new sub-document in the array with the same values for `array.key_2` and `array.date`, effectible duplicating the entry although with `array.counter` set to 1 instead of 3.

I'm using mongo version 4.2.1

**Update:**

Below there is a sample document before trying to run the operation on the second subdocument:

```
{
  "key_1": 1,
  "array": [
    {
      "key_2": 1,
      "counter" 1
    }, {
      "key_2": 2,
      "counter" 3
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I'm getting as a result when using `upsert`:

```
{
  "key_1": 1,
  "array": [
    {
      "key_2": 1,
      "counter" 1
    }, {
      "key_2": 2,
      "counter" 3
    }, {
      "key_2": 2,
      "counter" 1
    }
  ]
}
```

The operation is duplicating the second subdocument in array, but if `upsert` is not used then the array field is not created if it's not already in the parent document, which is the oposite of the expected behavior for `$addToSet` from what it says in the documentation.

**Update 2**

These are the steps to reproduce the issue:

Run the operation with `key_1` set to 1, and `upsert` disabled. None of the queries modifies the document. The `array` field is not created.

```
{
  "key_1": 1
}
```

Enable `upsert` and run the operation again. The `array` field is created in the second query:

```
{
  "key_1": 1,
  "array": [
    {
      "key_2": 1,
      "counter" 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Run the operation again twice more. The first query modifies the document twice:

```
{
  "key_1": 1,
  "array": [
    {
      "key_2": 1,
      "counter" 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Run the operation once more. The first query doesn't modifies the document. The second query creates a duplicate:

```
{
  "key_1": 1,
  "array": [
    {
      "key_2": 1,
      "counter" 3
    }, {
      "key_2": 1,
      "counter" 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample documents, that way it would be easy for someone to work on it..

Comment: @srinivasy , thanks for pointing that out, just edited the question.

Comment: Before second query, Can you confirm your first query is working correct, I suspect it would update `{
      "key_2": 1,
      "date": someDate,
      "conter" 1
    }` rather than `{
      "key_2": 2,
      "date": someDate,
      "conter" 3
    }` So basically it might be updating first found document in array, though you've used `$` is it working ? Can you test that..

Comment: @srinivasy , when `counter` reaches 3, the `console.log` is printing `!!!!1: 0 null 0 0` after the first query, that means that there were no modifications made to the sub-document. After that the second query kicks in and inserts the duplicate sub-document if `upsert` is enabled. If `upsert` is disabled, the `array` field is not automatically created as stated in the docs.

Comment: I agree, there might be an issue with second query but my intention is to check first that first query is working properly !! I think there is an issue with first query as well, we can figure it out how to do if there is no match(add sub-doc) !! But my ask is to check that `$inc` working properly or not..

Comment: @srinivasy , `$inc` works fine when a subdocument is a match for `key_2` and `counter` is less than 3 (I removed `date` from the example since it's rather distracting). It's just that the second query (without `upsert`, as it was initially intended) doesn't create the `array` field to insert the new sub-document with `counter` set to 1, that's why I added `upsert`, but it creates a duplicate sub-document with the same `key_2`, if there is already one in `array`.

Comment: @srinivasy , I just edited the question and added the steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Your first query should look like :: `db.UpsertArray.updateOne({ key_1: 1, array: { $elemMatch: { "key_2": 1, "date": 'someDate', "conter": { $lte: 1 } } } }, { $inc: { "array.$.conter": 1 } })` in order to properly update exact matching document, So for second query when you say:"but if the array doesn't have a sub-document with a given key" Do you mean by key_2 from subdoc doesn't exist in any of sub-docs in array of array field? Second query is not working because if conter is >3 modifiedCount will be 0 which is similar to no match on filter query, addToSet looks uniqueness on entire object

Comment: @srinivasy , yes, if an element with a given `key_2` is not present it should be created with value in `$addToSet`. I was trying to increase `counter` in an element in the array field up to three, and to detect when it reaches the maximum value returning `modifiedCount`. The operation should create the array field and the sub-document if any of those doesn't exist, everything with the minimum amount of queries. I guess I'll have to add an additional query to check whether `counter` has reached 3 at the beginning of the operation so that the duplicate entry is not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
var key_2Value = 2;

var firstFilterQuery = {
    key_1: 1,
    array: {
        $elemMatch: {
            "key_2": key_2Value,
            "date": 'someDate',
            "conter": { $lte: 3 }
        }
    }
}

var secondFilterQuery = {
    key_1: 1,
    "array.key_2": {$ne: key_2Value}
}

var defaultDoc = {key_2 : key_2Value, "date": 'someDefaultDate',counter: 1}
```

**Query :**

```
collection.bulkWrite([
            {
                updateOne:
                {
                    "filter": firstFilterQuery,
                    "update": { $inc: { "array.$.conter": 1 } }
                }
            }, {
                updateOne:
                {
                    "filter": secondFilterQuery,
                    "update": { $push: { array: defaultDoc } 
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
```

With the above query, you can achieve what you wanted in one DB call(at any given case only one 'updateOne' should update the DB), Output should look something like :

```
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "deletedCount" : 0.0,
    "insertedCount" : 0.0,
    "matchedCount" : 1.0,
    "upsertedCount" : 0.0,
    "insertedIds" : {},
    "upsertedIds" : {}
}
```

Comment: For some reason the `bulkWrite` query is not performing any modifications. I also tried using the values in the queries I used originally in the `bulkWrite ` but it didn't modify anything either.

Comment: @rraallvv : any error or just all zeros in output? Did you check your filter queries vs keys in documents does match?

Comment: This is the output: `{ acknowledged: undefined,
  deletedCount: 0,
  insertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  insertedIds: {},
  upsertedIds: {} }`

Comment: @rraallvv : yes this shouldn’t be the case if any docs matched with anyone of filter query, I’ve tested this query - Did you check if filter queries does match with keys in documents of your collection? Basically before running this query try running find queries to check whether data is properly retrieved based on given filters !!

Comment: The result is `ok: 1` with everything in zero with no `writeErrors` nor `writeConcernErrors`

Comment: @rraallvv : yes it will be all zeros if non of the filter queries does match then there will be no updates.. that might be what you’re seeing, Is there any issue on where you expect an update but query is not working? Try to execute on db first rather than thru code..

Comment: I tried running each operation separately on the mongo CLI, and then ported the queries to the Node.js app. I'm not sure why if wasn't working before, but it does what I wanted. Thanks so much.